# Cannot display the table after putting session checks in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, html-table

I added some `if` conditions and `php` sessions. Now it cannot display my program tables. I get an error : `Undefined variable $result on line 79`. In other action files the the tables work fine, they are displayed.

ac_directorProgramsYearsForm.php

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="form">
<form name="myform" action="ac_directorProgramsYears.php" method="POST">

<b>Programs:<b/>
<select name="program"> 
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT prog_name FROM program");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['prog_name']."'>".$row['prog_name'] ."</option>";
    }
    ?>  
</select><br/><br/>


<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ac_directorProgramsYears.php

```
   <?php 

      include 'connect.php';


      $programs = array(
       'bsc_computer_science',
       'bsc_psychology',
       'ba_finance',
       'ba_marketing',
       'ba_management'
      );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $program = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['program']); 

  session_start();

   if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){

        header("location:../../statistics/main.htm");
   }
   $username=$_SESSION['username'];

   if(isset($_POST['program'])){


        $_SESSION['program'] = $_POST['program'];


        if (in_array($program, $programs)){

             $sql = "SELECT year,a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $program";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }

        else {
             echo "No data found";
        }
     }
  }
?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="container">
   <table id="table" width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1">

   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>A1 </td>
        <td>A2 </td>
        <td>A3 </td>
        <td>L1 </td>
        <td>L2 </td>
        <td>L3 </td>
        <td>L4 </td>
        <td>L5 </td>
        <td>L6 </td>
        <td>L7 </td>
        <td>LAVG </td>
        <td>R1 </td>
        <td>R2 </td>
        <td>U1 </td>
        <td>U2 </td>
        <td>U3 </td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
<?php
    while($director=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$director['year']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['a1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['a2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['a3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l4']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l5']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l6']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['l7']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['lavg']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['r1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['r2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['u1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['u2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$director['u3']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table's display depends on the following `while condition`:

```
while($director=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

(I also believe that this is `line 79` from your error)

The error means that you didn't set the variable $result. Since it's not defined, it also has no value - so basically you're running the `mysql_fetch_assoc` function with an undefined variable instead of a query.

Now, I noticed that at the top of your code you had defined a variable named `$result` **but**, if you're taking a closer look - you define that variable in an `if condition`, and on the `else` option - you don't.

**Conclusion** - your script gets into the `else` block and therefore `$results` is undefined. Consider debugging your code in order to understand why the `if condition` returns false and going to the `else` block.

```
    if (in_array($program, $programs)){//This condition return false so...
         $sql = "...."
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    } else { //Your script runs this part of code
         echo "No data found";
        //$result is undefined in this case.
    }
```

**Please Notice** You're using `mysql_` which is deprecated. Consider using `PDO` or `mysqli_`.